# AngularJS, ui-sref-opts does not help reloading the app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm kind of stuck here in this situation, where I need my app to reload when changing from one "project" to another. I've tried many things and I have been searching over and over to find a solution.

My app is kind of complex, and if I try this in an isolated scenario it works perfectly, as it should. 
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref

```
<li ng-repeat="project in app.projects" ng-cloak>
    <a ui-sref="app.channel({projectId:project.id, channelId: project.channels[0].id})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}" class="active">
        <span>{{ project.name }}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Where the important part would be:

```
ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}
```

In my routes file I have many nested routes and views and I also have a custom authenicator set up. When I strip most of that down, it works. That's why I can't post any code example on Codepen or something similar.

Now my question is, is there any known issue with the UI-Router when using it with an authenticator, or maybe any other reason, why the ui-sref-opts won't reload the page?

Sorry for the kind of unspecific question, but maybe someone can help me out.

**EDIT: More information and code**

Ok, I'll try my best to give you the relevant information.

This is how my config.router.js is set up.

```
angular.module('app')
.run(
    // Authenicator is in here
)
.config(
    ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'JQ_CONFIG', '$authProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, JQ_CONFIG, $authProvider) {
            // ...

            .state('app.channel', {
                url: '/projects/{projectId}/{channelId}',
                views: {
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: 'tpl/channel/index.html'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                        function($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load('angularFileUpload').then(
                                function() {
                                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([

                                    ]);
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    ]
                }
            })

            // ...
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: This is too vague. We can't help you unless we see some more code.

Comment: Ok sorry. I added a part of my config.router.js. I wouldn't know what else would make a difference, if not the router. If you need something else, please tell me.

As I said, I absolutely don't have a clue why it shouldn't work.

Comment: You've said that the problem doesn't occur after stripping out the authenticator, implying the issue is there. Is there any code pertaining to that which you can share?

Comment: Here you go:
https://jsbin.com/xukumifaka/edit?js
Note that the semicolon at the end, is only there, so jsbin doesn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 0):

It could depend on the directive `cache-view="false"`. Usually, you have to put it on the `<ion-view>` directive in the page you are going, in your case in `tpl/channel/index.html`. But if you have nested view, you should put it in every view.

I had the same problem with a nested tab view. I had a series of tab and, inside one of them, another view with two tabs.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

    <!-- Home Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="MY FEED" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-home" ui-sref="main.wall">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-wall"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <!-- Messages Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="MESSAGES" icon-off="ion-ios-email-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-email"  ui-sref="main.message-tabs" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-messages"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

To make the reload work I had to put the directive `cache-view="false"` both in the container

```
<ion-view cache-view="false">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-color-active-positive tabs-striped tabs-message tabs-top">

    <!-- Message Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="MESSAGES"  ui-sref="main.message-threads" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}">
        <ion-nav-view name="subtab-messages"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <!-- Notification Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="NOTIFICATIONS" ui-sref="main.notifications">
        <ion-nav-view name="subtab-notifications"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

and in the page

```
<ion-view view-title="Message Threads" class="threads" cache-view="false">
    <ion-content class="has-tabs has-tabs-top">
...
```