# Why are `ui-sref-opts` settings being ignored?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularUI Router v0.2.13 and experiencing something different to what I read in the documentation with `ui-sref-opts` usage.

This HTML works great because it redirects the user back to my home page:

```
<a ui-sref="app.home">Back to home<a>
```

This HTML doesn't work because it still only redirects the user back to my homepage without updating the window location / URL:

```
<a ui-sref="app.home" ui-sref-opts="{location: true, notify: true}">Back home<a>
```

What could cause this? I tried upgrading to v0.2.15 which didn't fix the issue. The fact that redirection is working at all implies that something is up with AngularUI Router, and not that I've implemented it correctly (but maybe this assumption is false?)

This is the documentation I have been referring to: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#go

I also consulted this question, which may be a duplicate, but there is no answer there: [AngularJS, ui-sref-opts does not help reloading the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661233/angularjs-ui-sref-opts-does-not-help-reloading-the-app)

Comment: One reason this may not be a duplicate is that in this case the template is being used inside a modal.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net or http://plnkr.co ?